# Adminjs cant fetch data from mongo database. (NestJS)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs, adminjs

I am using adminjs in nestjs and mongoose

this is my product model
`const ProductModel = model<IProduct>('product', ProductSchema);`

this is my resource

````
resources: [
      {
        resource: ProductModel,
        options: { 
            navigation: { name: null }, 
            show: {
            before: async (request, response, context) => {
              throw new Error(
                'Data fetching has been disabled for this resource',
              );
            },
            handler: async (request, response, context) => {
              return {
                records: [],
              };
            },
          },
          list: {
            before: async (request, response, context) => {
              throw new Error(
                'Data fetching has been disabled for this resource',
              );
            },
            handler: async (request, response, context) => {
              return {
                records: [],
              };
            },
          },
      },
]```




this is error i get
````

[Nest] 23592  - 04/12/2023, 11:16:57 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\user\Documents\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

```
how to resolve this?
```

Comment: Have you actually performed a mongoose.connect inside your application?

Comment: yes, i have done it.   MongooseModule.forRoot(mongoCredentials.url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the Error.

I made adminjs module wait 5 seconds before initialize:

```
import { AdminModule as AdminJsModule } from '@adminjs/nestjs';
import { adminModuleOptions } from './admin-module.options';

AdminJsModule.createAdminAsync({
    useFactory: async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
      return adminModuleOptions;
    },
  }),
```

Then i made mongoose module wait 5 seconds before connecting:

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: async (): Promise<MongooseModuleOptions> => ({
      uri: mongoCredentials.url,
      connectionFactory: () => {
        const connection = mongoose.connection;
        setTimeout(() => mongoose.connect(mongoCredentials.url), 5000);
        return connection;
      },
    }),
  }),
```